# How to modify a object getting from a property decorator?

Tags: python

Let's say, here is a class `A`. It has a private value `_foo` which is a json string, and access it with property getter and setter.

The code is as the following:

```
import json

class A(object):
    _foo = '{"name":"name"}'

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return json.loads(self._foo)

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self._foo = json.dumps(value)
```

Usually, I use `foo` to do something like following:

```
a = A()
print(a.foo['name'])
```

But I'm in trouble when I want to modify it.

```
a = A()
print(a.foo)
# Out: {'name': 'name'}
a.foo['weight'] = 1
print(a.foo)
# Out: {'name': 'name'} # have no change
```

What I need to do is:

```
foo = a.foo
foo['weight'] = 1
a.foo = foo
print(a.foo)
```

Now, my question is how to implement this more intuitive and pythonic?

Comment: The whole concept of storing a dict as a json string looks weird to me. Why parse JSON every time the dict is accessed, and serialize JSON every time the dict is modified? Just load the JSON *once* and then store the thing as a dict.

Comment: There's no _easy_ way to do that with the syntax you want. `a.foo['weight'] = 1` isn't an assignment to `a.foo`. There is a hacky way you could do it if you want: instead of returning a normal dict (or list), wrap it in a proxy object that remembers who it belongs t, acts like a dict (or list) but overrides `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` (and `insert`), and assigns itself to `owner.foo`. But this is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: @Aran-Fey In practical use, I would add a object cache like `lru_cache`, but here, I remove it, because it don't affect my question.

Comment: If you could explain _why_ you want this (Aran-Fey is right—you almost always want to decode and encode JSON only "at the edges" and work with normal objects in between, not keep doing it over and over, just like you want to work with Unicode `str` instead of encoding and decoding back to UTF-8 around every operation), maybe we could show you a Pythonic way to do _that_ instead.

Comment: @abarnert I had thought of this, but I want to know is there any better way.

Comment: Any better way to do _what_? There's no good way to do what you're trying to do here, but there's probably a better way to do what you actually need to do.

Answer (score -1):

I think the correct way for you to do this is like this, dont save the dict as a string, but as an actual dict.

```
import json
class A(object):
   _foo = {"name":"name"}

   @property
   def foo(self):
       return self._foo

   @foo.setter
   def foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value

   def dump_foo(self):
       jsons.dump(self.foo)

   def __del__(self):
       self.dump_foo()
```

I cant see a real reason for you to dump the json file every time, edit it, use it, and when you are done dump it.

- If you still wish to print the dict (in a human readable manner) after this all you need to do is print(a.foo), due to the str conversion of a dict.

Comment: This means the property acts like a string, not like a dict. And what's the point of converting it to a dict and then throwing the result away at deletion time? Also, `jsons.dump(self.__foo)`?

Comment: @abarnert I think it should be ok now, I am guessing that at some point he might actually want to dump it into a file so I added it just in case.

Comment: Your setter and getter now serve no purpose, `dump_foo` till has at least two errors, and it's still useless to create a JSON string and then throw it away at del time.

Comment: @abarnert The setter he uses in his original question serves no purpose in this new implementation, but I dont know for what extra purpose he used the setter in the first place (this might be a simplistic approach). As for the the dumping on destruction, it is in case he actually wants to dump it to a file (as I stated in my previous comment-although at this point it doesn't include a file path).